# How to write JS function to show a paragraph of text to the page after 5 seconds from opening the page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have one paragraph in my html file. I need to write a Java Script function to show this paragraph, 5 seconds after opening the html file.

Comment: As you said, _you_ need to write a function. Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Not so hard, please check: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout...

Comment: You may check setTimeout

Comment: @Teemu  i wrote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it here is solution :

```js
var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},5000);

function myTimer()
{
var t="This is a Paragraph.";
document.getElementById("p").innerHTML=t;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            
          
    <script src="7b.js"></script>
    
        </head>
        
        <body>
      
    <p id="p"></p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Only that the text in the paragraph is updated on every 5 seconds. Use `setTimeout` instead.